# Add a value to the next line

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

So I have a script that updates one cell, the function is triggered weekly:

```
function updateCell() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a2').setValue('=Index(ImportData("URL HERE"),1,1)');
}
```

The thing is, this function only updates A2 (as it is set). What I want to do is update 3 cells and then go to the next line. Here is my FNX:

```
function RecordToSheet() {
  /*Record Date & Time*/
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a2').setValue('=NOW()');
  /*Record 1*/
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('b2').setValue('=Index(ImportData("URL1"),1,1)');
  /*Record 2*/
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('c2').setValue('=Index(ImportData("URL2"),1,1)');
}
```

As you see, the "getRange" is set to a2, b2, c2 (since a1, b1, and c1, is occupied by text). I need the script to "go to the next line" when it adds a value instead of change the current value. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) function to append the new values to the first empty row

Your code will look like this:

```
function RecordToSheet() {
 // make a data array with your row data 
 data = ['=NOW()','=Index(ImportData("URL1"),1,1)','=Index(ImportData("URL2"),1,1)']
 // Append the data array
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we want to add formulas to a spreadsheet we should use `setFormula()` / `setFormulas()`, not `setValue()` / `setValues()`.

Regarding going to the next cell, instead of A1 notation you could use the other forms like [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)